# Fade effect between two activities on Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, transition, fade

I am trying to add a fade effect when my splash screen activity finishes and/or when my main activity starts (ideally the main activity would fade in after the splash screen finishes but I am trying anything). I have tried many things involving animations and transitions, however none of them has worked so far. As you can see, I am not familiar at all with animations, and I am aware that my issue probably comes from my lack of knowledge about it. I have been reading a lot but still feel lost.

I was wondering if the fact that my SplashActivity doesn't have a layout set as a content view was affecting my results. I am only using a theme for the splash screen activity. Here is its implementation in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and the theme (initially without the 2 last items):

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_logo</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

I also tried to add a "fade in theme" to my MainActivity:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FadeIn" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
</style>
```

Regarding the animation, I saw that people were sometimes using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

while other times using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
   android:duration="1000" />
```

So I tried both... (optional question: what's the difference between them?)

In SplashActivity, I tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getBaseContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Also tried this in MainActivity's onCreate function:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
ViewGroup mRootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
Fade mFade = new Fade(IN);
// Start recording changes to the view hierarchy
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootView, mFade);
```

and

```
ViewGroup mRootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
mRootView.animate().alpha(0.0f); // at this point the view is totally transparent
mRootView.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(2000); // here the view becomes 100% visible instantly, there is no animation
```

That's the layout of the main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="16"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    ...
```

I checked that Transition animation scale was correct in my settings (I am using Android Studio's emulator for my tests). There was never a fade effect between my two activities. Please someone enlighten me.

.

.

For some reason, I have some kind of fade effect when I do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getBaseContext(),
                android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
startActivity(intent, bundle);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

I really don't understand. Of course it gets black then the fade-in effect of the main activity is working, but I don't understand why it works this way. If I delete a single line it stops working (I discovered it was working this way when I forgot to comment the second startActivity command). When I say I tried to delete a line, I also changed the order like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getBaseContext(),
                android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent, bundle);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out); // with or without this line, this code doesn't work.
// I must have tried pretty much all combinations without any success...
```

.

.

.

.

.

I'm just posting here what I've done after failing using all the previous solutions (that I've tried each separately). I am attaching a boolean extra to the intent when I want to get a fade-in effect when opening my next activity. Then in the onCreate method of the opening activity, I have:

```
boolean fadeEffect = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fade_in", false);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_main_layout);
if(fadeEffect) {
    mainLayout.setAlpha(0.f);
    mainLayout.animate()
              .alpha(1.f)
              .setDuration(1000)
              .start();
}
```

If someone needs help implementing this kind of solution, I can help.

Comment: Try using the default fade animations instead of creating your own. Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the Android default animations too but still no result...

Comment: What have you tried with default android anim? they should work just fine using the Fade class!

Comment: see my edits about MainActivity's onCreate function, not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Witch Android version are you using on your emulator?

Comment: Android 7.1.1, API 25 
My app's min sdk version = 21, target sdk version = 25 (buildToolsVersion=25.0.2)

Answer (score 4):

Add this option bundle to your startActivity method to make fade anim between two activities:

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(getContext(),
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle(); 
        startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

There is no need to add any further code to accomplish what you asked! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with animations between activities.

I know you said you tried it already but the

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

solution should work as long as you haven't messed around with other window animations. Perhaps by using some combination of possible solutions, it wasn't working properly? Try removing the others and sticking with this solution

Comment: I tried every solution separately and this was my only window animation. Just to make sure I've tried again but there is no effect. What I've done after none of my attempts succeeded, I have created a "fade-in" extra for my activities which potentially need to fade in. I will edit my question to add the code I've used because it makes my comment too long if I try to post it here.